Why the extrusion doesn't work?
I'm following this tutorial on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EV1elNFNSM
And I can't have a normal extrusion as on the video.
Does someone know why?
Here is what I have:

And I want to have this:


Would you mind showing screenshots of your object before extruding? And probably in Edit Mode so that we can see the actual mesh instead of just the outline? Maybe even better with Overlays > Face Orientation enabled? Because from what I see there I can only agree that it does not look correct.

This could be the result of attempting to extrude the split edges of an incoherent mesh? (Is this  EZ, in Global Transform Orientation?) The 'Normal' of a point or edge that's not part of a face defaults to the direction-from-object-origin.

please share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

I don't know how to check that, here is my file 
